# ng-repeat with angular translate

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, localization

I'm trying add internationalisation to my angular app using angular-translate, angular-i18n, and angular-dynamic-locale packages.

In simple tag i use $translate like:

```
<h3>{{'main.primitive' | translate}}</h3>
```

Where the 'main.primitive' is string value from my locale JSON file

'locale-[locale-name].json':

```
{
   "main.primitive": "some string",
   "main.array":[
      "elem",
      "elem"
   ],
   ......
}
```

And i have several locale-.json files for every locale.
Everything was greate before i tried to use ng-repeat in my views with translate filter.
Can anyone explain me how to properly use it to perform actions like:

```
 <div ng-repeat="elem in 'main.elem' | translate">
     <p>{{elem}}</p>
 </div>
```

Or i can only use objects and primitive data in my locale-.json files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the translate to the element, not the array.

```
<div ng-repeat="elem in 'main.elem'">
     <p>{{elem | translate}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: In this case Angular just use 'main.elem' as array string and content of <div ng-repeat> is: <p>m</p><p>a</p>...    Also translate throws warning for every string element in the console "Translation for m doesn't exist..."

Comment: Change from 'main.elem' to main.elem.

Comment: In this case Angular can't find main.elem and just hides div tag: <!-- ngRepeat: elem in main.array -->

Comment: Where's your array then? You have to change main.elem to the array reference you want to iterate through.

Comment: My array in locale-en_US.json file like and other string values. I can parse this file, retrieve array, bind it to the $scope and iterate it in ng-repeat, but i'm looking for approach to use ng-repeate with angular-dynamic-locale and translate packages.

Comment: You must parse the file first. The idea of the dynamic is to load the locale in runtime and translate any given string. So, you need to provide that given string, the array of strings in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="elem in 'main.elem'">
  <p>{{'main.array'+elem | translate}}</p>
</div>
```